# Installing Ubuntu on 64 bit Pentium i3

Tags: 64-bit, intel

Installing Ubuntu on 64 bit Pentium i3 HP ProBook 4530S that has Windows 7 Home Premium as the original OS.

I will be using it as a server to house a handful of websites of my own. I have partitioned the drive already and installed version ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64, and it is functional, working, etc.

Problem is, it says AMD 64 bit, I have Pentium. Is there a difference?? I see it in other things from time to time and am asking now because I never found out and am wondering if it may be important in this install and what I will be using it for. I do still have a small partition with the original Windows that came with the laptop, but it is set to automatically boot into Ubuntu if there's no input at boot-up.

I am aware of the Windows problems with security vulnerabilities, that is why I want to use Ubuntu, and I have never used it before.  ANY tips or advice are most welcome, and thanks to all!  :D